# type="search" works on PC but not Iphone?

Tags: ios, html

Hello Stackoverflow people,

Background:

I am building a privacy search engine at motherpipe.co.uk. I am adding functionality to the search box that allows a user to erase the text they have written with one click on the X to the right side in the searchbox. This is done by adding HTML5 functionality type="search".

Problem:

The code works on PC but not on Iphone and Ipad. The X does not show up. See https://motherpipe.co.uk/mobile/.

Question:

What do I need to change to get the X to appear and work correctly in Safari on iOS?

Any help much appreciated. Current HTML:

```
<form name="searchform" id="theform" action="search.php" method="GET" />
<input type="search" id="tag" class="textbox" name="q" autocomplete="off"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be anything in the HTML5 spec that requires the field-clear button. It is a feature that some browsers have added, but is not required. From the HTML5 spec -

> The difference between the Text state and the Search state is primarily stylistic: on platforms where search fields are distinguished from regular text fields, the Search state might result in an appearance consistent with the platform's search fields rather than appearing like a regular text field.

So, it isn't that the search field doesn't "work" - it will collect text and submit it to your server, its just that it has a different appearance between browsers.

In a quick test, Safari and Chrome on OSX added the "x" while Firefox did not, but all browsers submitted the data.